# How to add variant wise product description in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have multiple products in my shopify store . There are some products which have more than one variant . I use supply theme in shopify . I want my description to change on the basis of variant . But i am not able to do so . Any suggestions how this can be done ?

Shopify store url [paudhelagao.com](https://paudhelagao.com)

Comment: Search for any existing APP developed any custom APP or do some logic into existing theme code. by default, Shopify doesn't support it.

Comment: Do you have any experience with liquid and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use accenuate custom fields app or something similar, with those kinds of apps you could make custom fields/descriptions for your products. You need some "minimal" liquid knowledge to include those fields.